# Contact Form 7 checkbox to add a new class to a div

Tags: jquery, forms, plugin-contact-form-7

I am using the plugin “Contact Form 7” for WordPress and I’d like to customise the styling of a form.
So at some point the form contains a couple of checkboxes and the code generated by the plugin is:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox" id="check-brand" name="check-brand" type="checkbox" value="Brand">Brand</label>
</div>
```

What I’d like to do is add another class to the parent div when the user checks the checkbox. I have tried several code snippets from other posts but for some reason they don’t seem to do anything. The code I’m currently using is:

```
$(function(){
  $(".checkbox").on("click",function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
      $(".checkbox").addClass("selected");
    }else{
      $(".checkbox").removeClass("selected");
    }
  })
});
```

No matter what I’ve tried, the code doesn’t seem to add or change anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few more ideas I found the one that did the trick. So if anyone else is looking for something similar, here's what worked for me:

```
$(function() {
    $('.checkbox').click(function() {
        if ($(':checked', this).length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
    });
});
```